# Scope resolution operator and dependent name

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following test code

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>

struct PS
{
   template <typename U>
   static void foo()
   {
       std::cout<<"Some test code";
   }
};

template <typename T>
void bar()
{
   PS<T>::template foo<T>(); //won't compile without `::template`
}

int main()
{
   bar<int>();
}
```

ISO C++03 `14.2/4`: says

> When the name of a member template specialization appears **after . or ->** in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member **template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template**.

The Standard talks about `->` and `.` but not about `::`. Is it a defect in the C++03 Standard or am I missing something? Someone please enlighten me.

However the wording has been changed in `N3126`

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after **. or ->** in a postﬁx-expression or after a nested-name-speciﬁer in a qualiﬁed-id, and the object or pointer expression of the postﬁx-expression or the nested-name-speciﬁer in the qualiﬁed-id  depends on a template parameter (14.6.2) **but does not refer to a member of the current instantiation** (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be
>   preﬁxed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Can someone give an example to illustrate what `but does not refer to a member of the current instantiation` means in context of C++0x?

-PS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Standard talks about `->` and `.` but not about `::`.

The scope resolution operator (`::`) is part of the *qualified-id* referred to by "or after *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*."

The additional verbiage in C++0x is part of the resolution to [CWG defect 224](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#224).  Effectively, the definition of dependent names has been changed:

> The decision on whether a name is dependent or non-dependent should be based on lookup, not on the form of the name: if the name can be looked up in the definition context and cannot be anything else as the result of specialization, the name should be non-dependent.

Comment: Note that the Standard's use of "qualified-id" is wrong on many places, so best don't take it by word when it says "qualified-id". In the following variable declaration, for example, you need `::template`, but the nested name specifier does not appear in a qualified-id (but is nested in a `type-specifier`): `typename T::template alloc<int> a;`. In fact, the use of "qualified-id" in the Standard most often reflects the intent of meaning "qualified name".

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone give an example to illustrate what "but does not refer to a member of the current instantiation" means in context of C++0x?

I don't know if this is something that in fact behaves differently between an implementation of C++03 and C++0x.

```
template< typename Q >
struct A {
    template< typename T >
    void f( T );

    void g() {
        this->f< Q >( 5 ); // member of current instantiation is not ambiguous

        A< identity<Q> >().template f< 5 >(); // suppose A is partially 
// specialized on identity. Legal but confusing; need help from template keyword.
    }
};
```